# Delete the relations of relations in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to delete the relations of the relations of a model. If that makes any sense?

`$post->comments()->activities()->delete();`

So my post model has comments and comments have activities. Whenever I try to execute this, I get this error:

`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::activities()`

I know that this works:

```
$post->load('comments.activities');

foreach ($post->comments as $comment) {
    $comment->activities()->delete();
    $comment->delete();
}
```

But I think the first solution looks cleaner. Does anyone know why this won't work? Thanks.

**Edit**

The relationship method in Post model (polymorphic because there are comments on the post and comments on comments).

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Models\Comment', 'commentable');
}
```

The relationship methods in Comment model (polymorphic because I use activities on multiple models).

```
public function activities()
{
   return $this->morphMany('App\Models\Activity', 'subject');
}
```

Comment: have u declared the method in routes?

Comment: @Vicky I don't think route methods have anything to do with this problem.

Comment: can we see your relationships methods of your model?

Comment: @huuuk I updated the question with the relationship methods.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$post->comments->activities()->delete();
```

of course this will work only if you have one-to-many relations on both models

Comment: I tried this before but this creates another error. `Method activities does not exist.`. I use polymorphic relationships.

Comment: It seems that there is no `morphManyThrough` relation in Laravel. So at a glance I think that your approach with foreach loop is proper.

Answer (score 0):

Have you given table definition before writing??

```
protected $table = 'posts';
```

Can you little elaborate about your problem?